# user interface to search database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, codeigniter-2

I'd like to provide my users with a super easy to use search. I have about 8000 records in a mysql database and a handful of tables.

Currently I'm using a couple of text fields using SQL LIKE, OR LIKE, NOT LIKE etc...

I'd like to consolidate these into one search field, and allow them to specify AND, OR, NOT and hopefully where to search, be it the tags table, or the names table.

My application is in php5 built on Codeigniter. I'm not interested in apache lucene, it seems to be a bit overkill for my application.

Are there any solutions out there?

Thanks,
Blake

**EDIT: ** lucene isn't completely out, I'm just not convinced its my solution. I'm really suppriesed there isn't a parser out there that takes strings like
`apples tags:(green, red, macintosh, grannysmith) NOT orange`

Answer (score 2):

You may also try a simple HTML page and the POST features of PHP. Providing checkboxes for the users for the OR AND or NOT categories  along with a text box may be all you need to create custom queries depending on the complexity you are wanting to give them. Since your application is already written in PHP this would be a simple enough function.

Check out the php function mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. Using its different applications you can connect to your sql database and then perform queries using the custom fields from the HTML page.